# Checking whether AnimatedContainer is animating

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to add some sort of `StatusListener` to an `AnimatedContainer`? I'd like to be notified when an animation is done and when one starts.
Code with AnimatedBuilder:

```
        new AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: _animation,
          child: char,
           builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return new Transform(
                child: child,
                transform: new Matrix4.translation(new vect.Vector3(-100.0, y, 0.0)),
              );
           },
        )
```

code for the `_animation` and `_controller`:

```
_controller = new AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
  vsync: this,
);

_animation = new CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: Curves.linear,
)..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
    print('completed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`AnimatedContainer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) is just a convenience to make animations easier. If you want to have a listener you should look into implementing your own [`AnimationController`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html).
Have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331922/6414732) to have an easy example. You basically create an [`AnimationController`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) which is than used as a parent for an animation (e.g. [`CurvedAnimation`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/CurvedAnimation-class.html)). You can attach listeners to Animations.

**##--Edit--##**

Reacting to your code example, try this:

```
_controller = new AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
  vsync: this,
)..forward();

_animation = new CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _controller,
  curve: Curves.linear,
)..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
  if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
    print('completed');
});
```

with an AnimatedBuilder like this:

```
new AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: _animation,
  child: new Text('a'),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return new Transform(
      child: child,
      transform: new Matrix4.translation(new Vector3(0.0, _controller.value * 10, 0.0)),
    );
  },
);
```

this worked for me ;)

Comment: I added some working code. The problem with it is that there is no animation, the character just jumps to the new position.

Comment: I'm using this for my `transform` property: `transform: new Matrix4.translation(new Vector3(0.0, _controller.value * y, 0.0))`. Changing `y` and forwarding the animation makes the position change but without animation. It just jumps to the new location :/

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? How do you change y? You start the application, change y manually and expect the widget to animate to its new position?

Comment: When a tap on the screen is detected, I change the `y` value. I want the position of object to animate the the new `y` value position accordingly. This is exactly what it did with the `AnimatedContainer` but unfortunately I also need to add some sort of `EventListener`.

Comment: Hmm. I will look into this some more on the weekend. Unfortunately I have no clear idea in mind how to do what you want :(