# Run an action after end animation

Tags: flutter

is it possible to run a function after end this animation?
Thank you for you help

```
animation = CurvedAnimation(
       parent: controller,
       curve: Curves.linear,
      ).drive(Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call

```
animation.addStatusListener((status) {
   if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      // do your logic
   }
});
```

Look at the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial#animation-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

you have an `isCompleted` property on the `AnimationController`.

You can probably listen for this value?

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331922/11550065