# Flutter How to stop the LinearProgressIndicator when it reaches the end

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I need the LinearProgressIndicator to stop when it reaches the end instead of repeating, i gave the duration for example 10 secs, and i need that when the LinearProgressIndicator reaches the end of the seconds to stop.

```
late AnimationController controller;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData1() as Future<List<QuizInfo>?>;

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.repeat(reverse: false);
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

child: Container(
                        height: 7,
                        child: RotatedBox(
                          quarterTurns: -2,
                          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                            value: controller.value,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen for an animation to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316882/listen-for-an-animation-to-complete)

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. So you need to use the method `controller.animateTo(//seconds of the duration`):

```
  late AnimationController controller;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData1() as Future<List<QuizInfo>?>;

    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.animateTo(5.0);
    super.initState();
  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  child: Container(
                 height: 7,
                 child: RotatedBox(
                          quarterTurns: -2,
                          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                            value: controller.value,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                          ),
                        ),
               ),
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have to listen to the events of your animation in order to make a decision**
I believe that we have already answered that,Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316882/listen-for-an-animation-to-complete)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TweenAnimationBuilder` to easily achieve that.

```
  TweenAnimationBuilder(
    tween: Tween(end: 0.0), // change this from 0.0 to 1.0 and hot reload
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    builder: (BuildContext context, double value, Widget? child) {
      return LinearProgressIndicator(value: value);
    },
  )
```

So you can pass a variable to `end` param to control when to start the counter, for example declare `bool counting = false` and then pass `counting ? 0.0 : 1.0` to it.